# Reciprocal follow with user info

Tags: mysql, sql, relationship

Hi I have two tables `PAS_User` and `PAS_Follow` see diagram below,

[image: MySQL Tables involved]

What I am struggling with is a query for MySQL where the user can only see a list of other users where the relationship id reciprocal between them.

For a reciprocal (Mutual) the `PAS_Follow` table will have to records in, so say we have a user with and id of `1` and a user with an id of `2` the table will contain two rows of data with row 1 being:

`flow_follower_user_id = 1 && flow_followed_user_id = 2`

and row 2 being

`flow_follower_user_id = 2 && flow_followed_user_id = 1`

I have this query however it seems to show users that are not following the source user.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PAS_Follow.folw_followed_user_id AS user_user_id, PAS_User.user_first_name, PAS_User.user_last_name, PAS_User.user_avatar_url, PAS_User.user_sector, PAS_User.user_job_type, PAS_User.user_pass_token FROM PAS_User RIGHT OUTER JOIN PAS_Follow ON PAS_User.user_user_id = PAS_Follow.folw_followed_user_id WHERE `folw_followed_user_id` =**:id** OR `folw_follower_user_id` =**:id** AND `folw_deleted` = 0 ORDER BY PAS_Follow.folw_followed_user_id ASC
```

Where `**:id**` = 1 in this example.

This is for a direct message platform so it is important that when a user initiates the list of user they only see user that have a reciprocal relationship.

Any help would be gratefully received and I hope that the explanation of the problem is complete enough.

**** ANSWER FROM BELOW ****

Hope this helps someone else

```
SELECT foll_second.folw_follower_user_id AS user_user_id, user.user_first_name, user.user_last_name, user.user_avatar_url, user.user_job_type FROM PAS_Follow foll_first, PAS_Follow foll_second, PAS_User user WHERE foll_first.folw_follower_user_id = foll_second.folw_followed_user_id AND foll_second.folw_follower_user_id = foll_first.folw_followed_user_id AND foll_first.folw_follower_user_id =:id AND foll_second.folw_follower_user_id = USER .user_user_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an id in the user's table. If you have that, and let's call it `id`, you can use this:

```
SELECT * 

    foll_second.folw_follower_user_id AS user_user_id, 
    user.user_first_name, 
    user.user_last_name, 
    user.user_avatar_url, 
    user.user_job_type 

FROM 

    PAS_Follow foll_first,
    PAS_Follow foll_second,
    PAS_User user

WHERE 

   foll_first.folw_follower_user = foll_second.folw_followed_user 
   AND foll_second.folw_follower_user = foll_first.folw_followed_user
   AND foll_first.folw_follower_user = **:id**
   AND foll_second.folw_follower_user = user.id;
```

Which will give you a list of combinations of the two linking relations, and the user that is connected to `**:id**` by those relations.

This selects from all possible combinations of two follow-relations and a user those that correspond to something you want, which means:

- The two relations should connect to each other.
- That should be reciprocal actually
- The 'starting' user should be the one you're looking for
- The user row that's also in the result should be the one that the second relation points to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I do indeed have a user id `user_user_id` ideally I would like to get just a few columns only from the user table based on the `flow_followed_user_id` could you update your response to show how to do this, thanks for your help thus far I really appreciate it

Comment: Expanded on @Gijs answer `SELECT foll_second.folw_follower_user_id AS user_user_id, user.user_first_name, user.user_last_name, user.user_avatar_url, user.user_job_type FROM PAS_Follow foll_first, PAS_Follow foll_second, PAS_User user WHERE foll_first.folw_follower_user_id = foll_second.folw_followed_user_id AND foll_second.folw_follower_user_id = foll_first.folw_followed_user_id AND foll_first.folw_follower_user_id =:id AND foll_second.folw_follower_user_id = USER .user_user_id` thanks so much buddy you really saved me from going mad here